# Other than for related strength gain, why might abdominal / lower back hypertrophy be desired in both Olympic weightlifting and powerlifting?

Tags: abdominals, powerlifting, lower-back, olympic-weightlifting, hernia

I'm going through [Everett](https://www.amazon.com/Greg-Everett/e/B004Y8DKXI)'s ***Olympic Weightlifting: A Complete Guide For Athletes & Coaches*** .
The following quotes from the chapter ***Programming & Training*** caused me to think on the matter of
the abdominal / lower back hypertrophy in olympic weightlifting.

> [...]this type of hypertrophy serves little function for weightlifters.[...]However this rep range[7-12] is often appropriate for certain supplemental exercises,
> particularly abdominal and lower back training.

> [...]in cases of supplementary exercises such as abdominal, back, rehab,
> and hypertrophy work, we may control rest periods to achieve certain effects,
> such as sarcoplasmic hypertrophy when desired for specific areas.

[David Kirshen](https://www.amazon.com/David-Kirschen/e/B00JNFF3LO) seems to be in agreement with Everett in chapter ***Basic Muscular Anatomy*** of his ***Strength Training Bible For Men*** when it comes to the repetition range for abdominals in the context of [powerlifting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerlifting) :

> To train your abs for powerlifting, don’t bother with endless reps of crunches
> on the floor. Hit them hard with sit-ups over the glute ham bench, standing
> crunches with the pulldown machine or a band, spread-eagle sit-ups, side-bends
> with a dumbbell or band, and leg lifts. Keep the reps in the 8-to 15-rep range.

I also heard an opinion that abdominal workouts cannot really be done with the range
of 1-6 reps. I do not agree. As of now the exercises that I do for my abdomen are:

- [pullovers](https://youtu.be/hXtvUl6Orws) 2 reps or weighted(with ankle weights) leg raise 2-4 reps
- weighted lateral leg raise left side 2-4 reps
- weighted lateral leg raise right side 2-4 reps

Other than changing the weight categories, one thing that crossed my mind as the possible reason
for seeking abdominal hypertrophy is reducing
the risk if the [direct inguinal hernia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inguinal_hernia#Direct_inguinal_hernia).
The logic is that hypertrophy could possibly narrow [the inguinal triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inguinal_triangle) and thus reduce
the risk of this type of hernia.
For what yet other reasons might
abdominal / lower back hypertrophy be desired in olympic weightlifting?
Why might the high repetition range, i.e. >6, be preferred in training abdomen and
lower back?